# Update Target Button is disabled in Sql Server Database Schema Comparison

Tags: t-sql, deployment, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-2012, database-schema

I use Visual Studio 2013 Professional Update 4 in combination with multiple SQL Server 2012 Enterprise servers/instances. The Idea was to create a Version controlled deployment using a Visual Studio Solution with SQL Server Projects.

However for some reason the "Update Target" and "Generate Script" button is disabled.

[image: Schema Compare]

I can update the local database project from the sql server database but the other way around is not working. (see screenshot)

Google is not helpful at all although I found a few people with a similar problem.

[Update target button is disabled after schema comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17742638/update-target-button-is-disabled-after-schema-comparison)

[VS2012: Schema compare, update button disabled](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/797281/vs2012-schema-compare-update-button-disabled)

[VS2012 Schema compare buttons disabled](http://www.andrewburrow.net/vs2012-schema-compare-buttons-disabled/)

But none of this questions/blogposts is about Visual Studio 2013 and in addition none of the proposed solutions is working for me.

**Question:** Why is the Update Target button disabled and what do I have to change to fix this?

Note: Of course, I'm using the latest version of SQL Server Data Tools(12.0.50318.0)

Comment: The first link you provided actually solved the problem for me, http://stackoverflow.com/a/25204994/864274.  Check the error list window to see if there are any errors.  In my case, I had an invalid column name.

Comment: I have plenty off Errors mostly due to unresolved/ambiguous references. However, I don't think that visual studio schema compare should bother about this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update target button is disabled after schema comparison](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17742638/update-target-button-is-disabled-after-schema-comparison)

Comment: I've created VS UserVoice suggestion [Keep "update" and "generate update script" buttons enabled](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/17396128-keep-update-and-generate-update-script-buttons). Please vote if you agree.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was driving me nuts, as well.  I finally noticed a "warning" message stating "Cannot generate deployment plan due to an internal error".  Because of this, the Update and Generate Script buttons were both disabled.

I resolved this by closing Visual Studio, navigating to the folder containing the Database project and **removing all (*.dbmdl) files**.  I then restarted Visual Studio, re-ran the compare schema and the Update button was enabled.

Comment: I also had this "warning" and tried this solution, no joy.  There were also errors on external data sources/tables, excluding them didn't help, BUT: doing a schema compare without those externals present finally did work.  I accomplished this by creating a (temporary) new project, compared & updated that excluding the externals, then did a schema compare from the new project to the DB.

Answer (score 5):

The tip that helped me was to look at the error list. (View Menu, Error List). Once I cleared the errors (just the errors, the ones with the red X) I was able to  compare the schema again and the Update and Generate Scripts buttons were both enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Beside the generate script, click on OPTIONS and select only the objects for which you want to compare.
This and ONLY this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was because there was a circular reference between 2 views (2 views that referenced each other).  I didn't find out until I finally gave up and tried to manually create the views in the database.