# VS 2013 Sql Schema Compare: Update button disabled

Tags: visual-studio

I am working on an application with a project that uses Sql Schema Compare to update the database.
So to update the database I right click the project and select Schema Compare and I see the changes to be made, but the button to update the database is disabled (which I have circled in the image below). How do I fix this?
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update target button is disabled after schema comparison](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17742638/update-target-button-is-disabled-after-schema-comparison)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you might need to resolve all the errors displayed in the Error List first before the update button is enabled.

Hope this helps